# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when reading an avro file using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-avro

I'm trying to load an avro file using PySpark running on Dataproc Job:

```py
spark_session.read.format("avro").load("/path/to/avro")
```

I'm getting de flowing error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 166, in load
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o259.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.avroCompressionCodec()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(AvroOptions.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(AvroOptions.scala:80)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroOptions.<init>(AvroOptions.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroOptions.<init>(AvroOptions.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.inferSchema(AvroFileFormat.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:203)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Versions:

- PySpark: 2.3.4
- Spark: 2.3.4
- Dataproc: 1.3.56-debian9
- Avro: org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing this error because you are using `spark-avro` library for Spark 2.4.5 with Spark 2.3.4, you should use Dataproc 1.4 that has Spark 2.4.5 to solve this issue.

Comment: Another way to solve this issue is by using `spark-avro` by Databricks to version 2.3.x or earlier. [Databricks Spark Avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-4.0/README-for-old-spark-versions.md)